# Use of RFB or RDP for a single GUI application

Tags: html, user-interface, live-streaming, rdp, rfb-protocol

I’d like to be able to create a GUI that can be viewed over the network by a remote client.

One approach is to code the whole GUI in HTML5 and run it from a server such as Apache; the main difficulty with this is that the GUI includes at least one, sometimes two, windows containing live video streams (without any sound) and there doesn’t seem to be a good way of streaming live video into HTML5 - especially as it really *needs* to be live; a few seconds’ latency would be unacceptable.

Another approach (which I’ve done already, and actually works pretty well) is just to code the GUI as a desktop application (for example using Qt), and then to view the desktop remotely using VNC or Windows Remote Desktop. This gives the required responsiveness and lack-of-latency, but has the disadvantage that the whole OS desktop is accessible and not just my one application.

So, here is my question: is there a mechanism or a framework available that would enable me to use RFB (i.e. the protocol underlying VNC) or RDP (that underlying Windows Remote Desktop) to provide remote access to a single GUI application rather than a whole desktop?

Comment: My question appears to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When we comparing RDP and RFB the main deference is RDP only share metadata where RBF share whole frame buffer of the screen. So RBF is slow than RDP. VNC is using RFB where windows applications like Lync using RDP.

http://sandaruwmp.blogspot.com/2014/05/remote-desktop-application-with-rdp.html Here you can see a simple RDP example

Actually you can create an application that only shares a single application and also you can use many other protocols with RDP

here https://github.com/sandaru/RDAPP in this application it uses RDP with TCP that you can select only one application to show.

In this application it shares the desktop via RDP and listen to a TCP port you can send commands such as "stop selected processes", "Focus single application" and "share whole window". RDP react according to the TCP requests.

i hope this will be useful for you

NOTE: Above Source does not contain any NAT traverse mechanism.