# How to start a program over RDP on windows 7

Tags: windows, rdp

I want to start a command(cmd file) on remote windows 7/2008 hosts via rdp connection.

If it possible I want to operate from linux and python. If not - I can use windows.
So I have access to windows machines only via rdp. I have to start commands in automatically mode. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

Use WinRS, which is the proper solution for remote execution on Windows. See [Using WinRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163506.aspx).

There are *hacks* to allow RDP to execute something remotely (eg. [Can RDP clients launch remote applications and not desktops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops)), they are *hacks*. RDP does not have remote execution facilities.

If you want a Linux client, then install an SSH server on your Windows images. If you're brave you could give [OpenWSMAN](http://openwsman.github.io/) a shot, but frankly I'd stick to ssh.